# How to expand a Scrollbar in Tkinter when working with a pre-made user interface (pygubu)

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, pygubu

PyGubu is a simple Python program that allows to create UI interfaces with Tkinter widgets.

So I have created an UI like this one here on the right

[image]

Now, I want that Scrollbar to be as big as the Text widget.

"How can I make the Scrollbar bigger on Tkinter" has been asked many times on StackOverflow. In my case, I cannot use the functions pack() or grid() as I am importing an already semi-finished UI

The code I use to load the Text and the Scrollbar is as the following:

```
    self.log = builder.get_object('log')
    self.log_scroll = builder.get_object('log_scroll')
    self.log.config(yscrollcommand=self.log_scroll.set)
    self.log_scroll.config(command=self.log.yview)
```

Now, I see two possibilities here:

---

### 1. Solving from PyGubu

The easiest way should be setting some attributes from PyGubu to solve this. Yet, PyGubu allows me to change only a minor number of attributes of the Scrollbar, and none of them seems to be relevant

### 2. Solving from Python

And here I have no idea about what to do. I don't know if I can use pack() and grid() while using a custom-made interface

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While writing the question, I've found a not-so-intuitive answer, still the best one:

[image]

The property "sticky" is the one who can solve the problem. What is not-so-intuitive is that you can select multiple squares ctrl+click. If you are used to work with Tkinter, it would probably not surprise you, but in my case (first day with Tkinter) I can just consider myself lucky

Comment: Should be `sticky='ns'`, thererfore you habe to select the **mid top** and **mid bottom**.

Comment: @stovfl You cannot do that apparently. To set `sticky='ns'` (which is correct, that is what I needed to do) you need to select the mid top, the mid bottom AND the central one :P

Comment: What is **central on** only, supposed to set?

Comment: It's like not setting sticky at all, from what I can see. Same thing if you want to set `sticky='we' `: you have to select the central one as well. If you want nesw, you probably need to select all the nine squares (I need to check)

Answer (score 1):

When you set the sticky option in Pygubu, even when all three squares are highlighted, it sets NS (North South), which is the expected result.
[image]

The generated code will also just have 'ns', like this:

```
self.scroll_bar.grid(column='0', row='0', sticky='ns')
```

Selecting the central/middle square in Pygubu won't affect 'ns'. It should still give you the expected result when you have the 3 squares highlighted.